# Getting a loop to build a string correctly

Tags: c#, loops

I'm trying to pull the tournament age from this webpage:

http://www.reddishvulcans.com/uk_tournament_database.asp

I'm trying to create a string based on the valid ages for entry for each table.

For example, if the "Carling Cup" is enterable by 7 year olds, then a string would be generated like "U7", or if it's enterable by 7, 8, and 9 year olds, the resulting string will be "U7, U8, U9".

I've made a start, however my logic will break if the ages go like this "Under 7s, **Gap here where no under 8s**, Under 9s".

Here is my code:

```
public static List<Record> getRecords()
    {
        string url = "http://www.reddishvulcans.com/uk_tournament_database.asp";
        var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = Webget.Load(url);
        var root = doc.DocumentNode;
        var ages = root.SelectNodes("//div[@class='infobox']/table/tr[5]/td/img");

        List<String> tournamentAges = new List<String>();
        String ageGroups = "";
        List<String> ageString = new List<String>();

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < ages.Count(); i++)
        {

            if (ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope") == "images/2016/u6_Yes.gif")
            {
                if (!ageString.Contains(" U6 ")) {
                    ageString.Add(" U6 ");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope") == "images/2016/u6_.gif")
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope") == "images/2016/u7_Yes.gif")
            {
                if (!ageString.Contains(" U7 "))
                {
                    ageString.Add(" U7 ");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope") == "images/2016/u7_.gif")
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope") == "images/2016/u8_Yes.gif")
            {
                if (!ageString.Contains(" U8 "))
                {
                    ageString.Add(" U8 ");
                    continue;
                }                
            }
            else if (ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope") == "images/2016/u8_.gif")
            {
                continue;
            }
             // Checks until u16.gif

            foreach (String a in ageString)
            {
                if (a != "")
                {
                    ageGroups += a;
                }

            }

            ageString.Clear();
            if (ageGroups != "")
                  {
                tournamentAges.Add(ageGroups);
            }
            ageGroups = "";
            }
        }
}
```

To be clear, I'm having trouble with the loop logic.

The flow currently goes like this:

```
Loop through current list of images
    If > u6_Yes.gif 
        Concatenate u6 to ageString
    else
        Continue
```

However it will continue back to the start and get stuck in an infinite loop, How can I make it gracefully handle when u6_.gif is gone, ignore it and go to the next?

Comment: Since it's all comparisons why don't you use a `switch` clause on  `ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope")`? That should improve readability at least a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just simplify your loop like this?

```
if (ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope") == "images/2016/u6_Yes.gif")
{
    if (!ageString.Contains(" U6 "))
    {
        ageString.Add(" U6 ");
        continue;
    }
}

if (ages[i].GetAttributeValue("src", "nope") == "images/2016/u7_Yes.gif")
{
    if (!ageString.Contains(" U7 "))
    {
        ageString.Add(" U7 ");
        continue;
        }
    }
}

(...)
```

just remove all those `else if` blocks...

Also, you should consider extraction `src` attribute from ages array. You can use Linq and make your loop a lot simplier. Something like this:

```
List<String> ageString = new List<String>();
List<string> imageSources = ages.Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("src", "nope").StartsWith("images/2016/u") && x.GetAttributeValue("src", "nope").EndsWith("_Yes.gif")).ToList();
foreach (var src in imageSources)
{
    ageString.Add(" " + src.Substring(11, 2).ToUpper() + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nino, that's an interesting take. I've tried your method of using Linq, but ageString list ends up with 1000+ elements. How would I seperate the ages within this? (For example 7-16)

Comment: I've edited an answer. Now sources are filtered with StartsWith and EndsWith. Sorry, I cannot test my answer because of thir party class you're using (Webget), but I hope you'll get the idea what I am suggesting...

Comment: Thanks for your input, Webget is a part of HTMLAgilityPack I believe. I will investigate your answer further,